# Text file with unknown header does not print propperly

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting, text

I have a bunch of text-files that always come along with a backup file:

file.TXT
file.BAK

the `*.TXT` file contains a header like this:

`.V3  PL=62    MB=1     MT=1     DR=TMTYM          FL=0     FT=0     #`

Special characters like the German `ä` `ö` `ü` are not recognized when printed to the command line with `cat` I get `��`.

The file contains footnotes in the following format:

```
.FN 4
 &&FN&
```

**Does anyone know what program was used to create those files?** *(guessing it is from the MS-DOS aera)* and any tool, to convert them to any readable format text/markdown/tex/LibreOffice?

`file -i file.TXT` prints: `OTT3.TXT: application/octet-stream; charset=binary`

`od -tc < OTT3.TXT | head` prints:

```
0000000   .   V   3           P   L   =   6   2                   M   B
0000020   =   1                       M   T   =   1                    
0000040   D   R   =   T   M   T   Y   M                                
0000060           F   L   =   7   0                   F   T   =   0    
0000100                   #  \r  \n   .   F   [  \r  \n 377  \r  \n   .
0000120   F   N       1  \r  \n   #   A   L       N  \r  \n   #   A   U
0000140       B  \r  \n 006 001   R   F  \a   0   9  \r  \n  \b   &   &
0000160   F   N   &  \b   D   a   s       d   e   r       H   a   u   p
0000200   t   m   a   n   n       d   e   n       S   c   h   a   u   p
0000220   l   a   t   z       d   e   r       H   a   n   d   l   u   n
```

`chardetect file.TXT` prints:

```
OTT3.TXT: Windows-1254 with confidence 0.6400783871057183
```

If I try to use `pandoc` for conversion, I get:

```
UTF-8 decoding error in OTT3.TXT at byte offset 76 (ff).
The input must be a UTF-8 encoded text.
```

[I uploaded one of those files to github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/0unknwn/strange-text-files/main/OTTONEN.TXT)

Comment: The `\n\r` suggest you are right about MS-DOS. Have you tried `dos2unix`?

Comment: @Quasímodo, THX for the answer! by running: `dos2unix -n file.TXT out.txt` I get: `dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x06 found at line 7
dos2unix: Skipping binary file file.TXT`

Comment: You are welcome! I hadn't noticed the 0x06. That is an Acknowledge byte. It would be quite weird to have it in a text file, indeed. Hope someone can give you more help.

Comment: Can you link us to one of these files so we can download and try solutions on it?

Comment: Just to get people thinking along the right lines: http://old.easyco.com/easydocs/4word/4w.manual.dot.htm http://justsolve.archiveteam.org/wiki/WordStar#Control_characters

Comment: @terdon I updated the post with a [github-link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/0unknwn/strange-text-files/main/OTTONEN.TXT).

Comment: it's the backup files which is created by an editor when you edit some files and they can be discarded as they are not useful

Comment: How does the file end? Some file-formats have the magic numbers at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The file you prvided could have been generated using WordStar for DOS v3:

- File starts with .V3
- header line could mean (only the entries I can decypher)

  - PL=65 : page length is 65 lines
  - MB=1 : margin at bottom is 1 line
  - MT=1 : margin at top is 1 line
- use of DOS line breaks for paragraph delimiter
- German umlauts coded in CP850 (DOS)
- use of 8d0a combination for regular line breaks
- use of 1f for active hyphen
- no default file extension, so user picks her own (".txt" quite often used)
- backup copies by default saved with ".bak" extension
- use of 1a to mark end of file

also some [other control characters used](http://justsolve.archiveteam.org/wiki/WordStar) but not enumerated here are plausible

For the file you linked to you could try the following:

```
cat OTTONEN.TXT | tr -d '\001\006\007\032\215' | tr '\037' '-' | dos2unix | iconv -f cp850 | sed -e '/^\(.V3\|#A[LU]\|.LS\|RD[0-9]\)/d' > OTTONEN2.txt
```

And then just print the created file as text (using the preformatted line breaks and hyphenation